# App Display is not proper in different Tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I've developed an APP for Android Tablet whose spec is as follows
Device Name: Croma CRXT1131
Res: 1024 x 768 pixels - 163ppi - 7.85 inch

In this croma tab all views are proper.

But my APP is stretched in Dell Venue 8 inch tab 1280 x 800 pixel - 8 inch - 188 dpi.

Both device are actually mdpi screen so I'm not sure why the display is stretched in Dell Venue 8 inch tab.

Any help or information will be really helpful.

Also please recommend some books or sites where I can learn about developing APPS for different Android Screens

Regards,
Arun V

Answer (score 0):

Refer these links:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Hope this helps :)